# Copy file from Linux server to windows server through ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, windows-server-2008

I have to copy file from one folder on linux server to windows server(2008) through ssh. The servers do not lie on same network. I have gone through many examples that use `scp` command, but didn't get any to copy from linux server to windows server.
How can I do so? I cannot use Samba due to security issues.

Comment: what errors did you get with scp?

Comment: Does the Windows box have an SSH server installed?  Windows does not support SSH out of the box.  Please be clear, are you trying to initiate the copy from the Linux side or the Windows side?

Comment: You've told us nothing about the examples you've tried nor the resources available except that you can't use Samba, without explaining why this creates a security issue. Nor have you provided any details of of why the things you have tried did not work. I suppose if you get enough answers, eventually someone might get lucky, but if you explained the problem more fully the you've got a much better chance of getting a solution.

Answer (score 2):

if you have ssh access from windows to linux, you could use winscp. It uses ssh to do the connection and it has graphical interface. So, all you need is ssh connection from win to linux.

Answer (score 1):

Download *pscp* [from here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html). Then from the windows machine execute:

`C:\TEMP> pscp user@linux.machine:/path/to/file .`

This copies *file* to *C:\TEMP\file* and assumes that you have put *pscp.exe* in a directory listed in your *PATH* environment variable.